# I want to DELETE my mysql table record, but it doesn't work, with onclick popup

Tags: php, mysql

my code directly goto "delete_product.php" and delete the record, not showing pop up.

```
 echo "<td><a href='delete_product.php?id=".$sno."' onClick='return confirm('Do you want to delete?');'>Delete</a></td>";
```

Comment: try this onClick="return(confirm('Are you sure to delete'));"

Comment: Can you add the php file to your post?

Comment: add your php code here

Comment: You should parse quotes in your syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You have there problem with quotes, the inner ones need to be escaped by backslashes.

```
onClick='return confirm(\'Do you want to delete?\');'
```

Comment: yes, it working in mozilla, but not work in chrome, wht i do?

Comment: echo "<td><a href='delete_product.php?id=".$sno."' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this record?\")'>Delete</a></td>";

Comment: @karthik: after the backslash has to be a single quotes `'` as I wrote, you put there double-quotes `"`.

Comment: i tried both, if i give ' quote means didn't show the popup and directly delete the record, if i give the " quote means it work in "mozilla" and "IE", i don't understand wht is the prblm is?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write it in html instead in php

```
?>
<td><a href="delete_product.php?id=<?php echo $sno?>" onClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete?');">Delete</a></td>
<?php
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use for link

```
<a href=delete_product.php?id=$sno>Delete</a>
```

for delete on delete_product.php

```
$delete_id=$_GET['id']; 
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id='$delete_id'") or die(mysql_error());
```